# Regex to catch text not containing a string and ending with an extension

Tags: regex, webpack

I'm trying to have 2 regex, one catching string containing 'critrical' and ending with '(s)css' and second one for string which don't contain 'critical' (with the same extentions rule).

I already have the first one and it is `/.*?critical.*\.s?css$/`

But I can't manage to make the second one. I thought it would be as easy as `/.*?(?<!\.critical).*\.s?css$/`. But, seems it's not that easy as it doesn't work...

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex(for the string not containing the word critical and containing css in the end):

```
^(?!.*critical).*s?css$
```

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DlNYuw/3)

**Explanation:**

- `^` - asserts the start of the string
- `(?!.*critical)` - **negative lookahead** to validate that the word `critical` is not present in the string
- `.*` - matches 0+ occurrences(greedily) of any character except a new line
- `s?css` - matches an optional `s` followed by `css`
- `$` - asserts the end of the string

And, for the string containing the word critical and containing css in the end, you can try:

```
^(?=.*critical).*s?css$
```

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DlNYuw/4)

The only difference with this regex is that it uses a **Positive lookahead** to make sure that the string `critical` exist somewhere in the string.